# alias in ash - limitation, syntax issue?

Tags: alias, openwrt, syntax, ash

I'm running OpenWRT in a NAS (WD-MBL) and putting together a set of aliases to make maintenance easier via the command line.

These work as expected:

```
alias shutdown='sync && wait && sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sda && wait && sudo halt'
```

Shuts down the NAS gracefully.

```
daemon='sudo /etc/init.d/rsyncd status'
```

Tells me the `rsync` daemon's status.

```
drivechk='sudo dmesg | grep -i ext4-fs | grep -i sda'
```

Alerts me to filesystem issues caused by a bad shutdown requiring `e2fsck`.

```
tempchk='sudo smartctl -d ata -A /dev/sda | grep Temperature | cut -c 5-8,87-89'
```

Tells me the drive temperature.

But there is one which I have not been able to get to work:

`fschk='df -h | grep -vE '^Filesystem|/dev/root|tmpfs'| awk '{ print $5 " " $1}'`

The stanza run from the command line works as expected:

```
~$ df -h | grep -vE '^Filesystem|/dev/root|tmpfs'| awk '{ print $5 " " $1}'
53% /dev/sda1
37% /dev/sda3
~$
```

If I add this to the `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh` file, log out and log in again I get this on the terminal:

```
~$ ssh user@192.168.1.3
--- snip ---
BusyBox v1.33.2 (2022-02-16 20:29:10 UTC) built-in shell (ash)

alias:  }' not found

~$
```

If I then run the alias I get this:

```
~$ fschk
>
```

If I query the `alias` list from the command line, I see that the one I added is shown differnetly in the printout:

```
~$ alias
--- snip ---
fschk='df -h|grep -vE '"'"'^/dev/root|tmpfs'"'"'|awk '"'"'{print  '
--- snip ---
:~$
```

But not in the file where it remains as I typed it:

```
~$ cat /etc/profile.d/custom.sh
--- snip ---
alias fschk="df -h|grep -vE '^/dev/root|tmpfs'|awk '{print $5 " " $1}'"
--- snip ---
~$
```

It seems that `ash` has a different/reduced version of `alias` but I cannot figure this one out.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best,

PCL

Answer (score 2):

Your alias,

```bsh
alias fschk="df -h|grep -vE '^/dev/root|tmpfs'|awk '{print $5 " " $1}'"
```

is a double-quoted string.  The shell will therefore expand both `$5` and `$1` in the string when it defines the alias.
To avoid this, make sure to escape the dollar signs.

The alias also contains double quotes that need to be escaped if you don't want them to interrupt the string.

```bsh
alias fschk="df -h | grep -vE '^/dev/root|tmpfs' | awk '{ print \$5 \" \" \$1}'"
```

Or, simplified:

```bsh
alias fschk="df -h | awk '!/^\/dev/root|tmpfs/ { print \$5, \$1 }'"
```

Or, as a shell function (in which case you don't have any issues with quoting at all):

```bsh
fschk () {
    df -h | awk '!/^\/dev/root|tmpfs/ { print $5, $1 }'
}
```

or, as a function that takes a list of filesystems to avoid extracting the `df` info for:

```bsh
fschk () {
    df -h | (
        IFS='|'
        pat="${*:+^($*)}" awk 'ENVIRON["pat"] == "" || $0 !~ ENVIRON["pat"] { print $5, $1 }'
    )
}
```

You would use this like

```bsh
fschk tmpfs /dev/root
```

In fact, I would suggest that you rewrite all of your aliases as shell functions.  Aliases are only really useful for trivial things.

Comment: I'm _very_ new to to `ash`/`bash` so I look for working examples on the web, see if they work for me and, if needed, try to adapt them. I found this one and as it worked properly _as-is_ from the command line, I set it up as an `alias`. Curious to know why it works properly from the command line but not when called as an `alias`? THXS

Comment: @Groucho As I describe in my answer, because you fail to define the alias properly due to issues with quoting and due to the shell expanding what it thinks are shell variables in the aliased command string.

Comment: This was the one that worked: `alias fschk="(df -h | grep -vE '^Filesystem|/dev/root|tmpfs'|awk '{print \$5 \" \" \$1}')"` - command-line enclosed in parentheses was needed - apparently some issue with ash. THXS

Comment: @Groucho The parentheses are not needed in the `ash` shell. You also don't need the `grep`.  See the simplified example in my answer.

Comment: I'll check that out again. THXS